# What's the difference between Activity and Context?

Tags: android

I wonder what's the difference between Activity and Context?
Because when I initialize WebView and getScreenSize,I replaced all the context with activity, and it works fine.

Comment: Learn some more about object-oriented principles and inheritance. The `Activity` class indirectly extends `Context` therefore all Activities *ARE* Contexts. The reverse is not true however.

Answer (score 2):

`Activity` extends `Context`, that's why it worked. Usually, when you need to pass a `Context` from your activity, you have to pass `this`.

This is what a `Context` is, according to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html).

> Interface to global information about an application environment. This is an abstract class whose implementation is provided by the Android system. It allows access to application-specific resources and classes, as well as up-calls for application-level operations such as launching activities, broadcasting and receiving intents, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Context is 'like your activity'. Why what you did worked is because your activity tells you the context of the application. So then it knows where the webview displays.